# select level from dual connect by level<=4 how it works internally

Tags: oracle

I know level usage along with hierarchical queries but I am not able to understand how to analyze this:

```
(select level from dual connect by level<=4)
```

query works internally and how it is generating numbers.

For generating numbers I had another way that is:

```
select r from (select rownum r from all_objects) e where r<=10
```

it will generate the first 10 numbers. But I am not able to understand how level is working internally.

Please explain why!

Answer (score 4):

This builds a hierarchical query. The `connect by` defines how to walk from the parent node to its children node and their children's children node. In this case, your definition of connection is only when `level >= 4`. The trick here is that `level` is pseudo column, like `rownum`, so the condition is satisfied only by the less-than equal number supplied (in this case 4).  You can also do this with rownum:

```
select level from dual connect by rownum <= 4;
```

`Level` is used to count the depth of the connections, so a parent would be 1, a child 2, a child of the child 3, etc. So think of it as a rownum for hierarchical queries.