# MSSQL equivalent to oracle CONNECT BY LEVEL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I need to get equivalent to this Oracle query but in MSSQL

```
SELECT (POZ.NO) AS NO
FROM (
    SELECT LEVEL NO
    FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1
    ) POZ
```

Comment: Can you explain what CONNECT BY LEVEL does in Oracle?. What is the expected result for you query?, Chances are that MSSQL experts are not Oracle experts

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
select t.seqnum AS NO
    from (select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
  from information_schema.columns
 ) t
   where seqnum <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no Oracle experience, but by reading [this](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/connect-by-clause/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184715/select-level-from-dual-connect-by-level-4-how-it-works-internally) I figure that op's query just wants to create a table with a single column "No" ranging from 1 to constant (1 in this case).

There are many ways to do this if you look around. However, since the oracle query runs on a hierarchical traversal pattern, I guess the solution with equivelant logic is tsql recursion:

```
WITH t(No) AS (
  SELECT 1     -- Seed Row
  UNION ALL
  SELECT No + 1 -- Recursion
  FROM t
  where No+1<=10
)
SELECT *
FROM t
```

Enclosing the resulting table in parentheses to form a derived table is used in the same way, so I am omitting it.